# Generic performance vs. Type performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-core

I have several methods where I need to convert data (arrays) from one type into the other.
Sometimes I can work with generics, sometimes not, because the type is loaded from a configuration after the object is created. Since I need many different type conversions I created a ArrayConvert class that is able to handle this for me. My data is extremely large and I have to do it very that of course I try as much as possible to prevent the conversion, but in my situation this is not always possible.

**The ArrayConvert class looks like following:**

```
 public static class ArrayConvert
    {
        public delegate void Converter(Array a1, Array a2);

        static readonly Dictionary<(Type srcType, Type tgtType), Converter> converters = new Dictionary<(Type fromType, Type toType), Converter>();

        static ArrayConvert()
        {
            converters.Add((typeof(float), typeof(int)), FloatToInt);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
        public static void FloatToInt(Array a1, Array a2)
        {
            int N = a1.Length;
            var srcArray = (float[])a1;
            var tgtArray = (int[])a2;

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                tgtArray[i] = (int)srcArray[i];
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
        public static void FloatToInt(float[] a1, int[] a2)
        {
            int N = a1.Length;
            var srcArray = a1;
            var tgtArray = a2;

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                tgtArray[i] = (int)srcArray[i];
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
        public static void Convert(Type srcType, Array srcArray, Type tgtType, Array tgtArray)
        {
            if (converters.TryGetValue((srcType, tgtType), out var converter))
            {
                converter(srcArray, tgtArray);
                return;
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
        public static void ConvertGenericFast<TSrcType, TTgtType>(TSrcType[] srcArray, TTgtType[] tgtArray)
        {
            if (converters.TryGetValue((typeof(TSrcType), typeof(TTgtType)), out var converter))
            {
                converter(srcArray, tgtArray);
                return;
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining | MethodImplOptions.AggressiveOptimization)]
        public static void ConvertGenericSlow<TSrcType, TTgtType>(TSrcType[] srcArray, TTgtType[] tgtArray)
        {
            Convert(typeof(TSrcType), srcArray, typeof(TTgtType), tgtArray);
        }
    }
```

When I know write a benchmark around this conversion methods, I can see pretty weird results.

**Here's the benchmark class:**

```
  public class Tester
    {
        public readonly static int N = 100000;
        public readonly static float[] SrcData;
        public readonly static int[] TgtData;

        static Tester()
        {
            SrcData = new float[N];
            TgtData = new int[N];

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                SrcData[i] = i;
                TgtData[i] = i;
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ConvertWithType() => ArrayConvert.Convert(typeof(float), SrcData, typeof(int), TgtData);

        [Benchmark]
        public void ConvertWithGenericFast() => ArrayConvert.ConvertGenericFast<float, int>(SrcData, TgtData);

        [Benchmark]
        public void ConvertWithGenericSlow() => ArrayConvert.ConvertGenericSlow<float, int>(SrcData, TgtData);

        [Benchmark]
        public void ConvertWithKnownDirectWithType() => ArrayConvert.FloatToInt(SrcData, TgtData);

        [Benchmark]
        public void ConvertWithKnownDirectWithArray() => ArrayConvert.FloatToInt((Array)SrcData, (Array)TgtData);
    }
```

**Benchmarks:**

Runtime = .NET Core 3.1.2 (CoreCLR 4.700.20.6602, CoreFX 4.700.20.6702), X64 RyuJIT; GC = Concurrent Workstation

Array Size: 10.000

```
|                          Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|-------------------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
|                 ConvertWithType | 8.518 us | 0.0080 us | 0.0071 us |
|          ConvertWithGenericFast | 8.684 us | 0.1163 us | 0.1088 us |
|          ConvertWithGenericSlow | 8.482 us | 0.0028 us | 0.0023 us |
|  ConvertWithKnownDirectWithType | 8.334 us | 0.0027 us | 0.0024 us |
| ConvertWithKnownDirectWithArray | 8.562 us | 0.0893 us | 0.0746 us |
```

Array Size: 100.000

```
|                          Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median |
|-------------------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|                 ConvertWithType | 68.40 us | 0.772 us | 1.372 us | 67.77 us |
|          ConvertWithGenericFast | 68.03 us | 0.627 us | 0.770 us | 67.83 us |
|          ConvertWithGenericSlow | 69.11 us | 0.944 us | 0.883 us | 68.90 us |
|  ConvertWithKnownDirectWithType | 67.45 us | 0.689 us | 0.611 us | 67.34 us |
| ConvertWithKnownDirectWithArray | 67.24 us | 0.425 us | 0.398 us | 67.20 us |
```

Array Size: 1.000.000

```
|                          Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median |
|-------------------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|                 ConvertWithType | 693.9 us |  8.06 us |  7.54 us | 693.4 us |
|          ConvertWithGenericFast | 800.2 us | 26.99 us | 79.58 us | 865.8 us |
|          ConvertWithGenericSlow | 872.7 us |  6.27 us |  5.86 us | 870.1 us |
|  ConvertWithKnownDirectWithType | 743.3 us | 24.66 us | 71.94 us | 704.1 us |
| ConvertWithKnownDirectWithArray | 870.9 us |  7.82 us |  7.32 us | 866.5 us |
```

Array Size: 10.000.000

```
|                          Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|-------------------------------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|
|                 ConvertWithType |  8.739 ms | 0.1120 ms | 0.0993 ms |
|          ConvertWithGenericFast | 10.052 ms | 0.0918 ms | 0.0859 ms |
|          ConvertWithGenericSlow | 10.015 ms | 0.0563 ms | 0.0439 ms |
|  ConvertWithKnownDirectWithType | 10.070 ms | 0.0058 ms | 0.0045 ms |
| ConvertWithKnownDirectWithArray | 10.096 ms | 0.0996 ms | 0.0931 ms |
```

Why is the ConvertWithType always faster except the first two with 10.000 and 100.000 elements?
Why is the ConvertWithKnownDirectWithType not the fastest?
Why is there almost no difference between ConvertWithGenericFast  and ConvertWithGenericSlow?
Why is there in 1.000.000 elements such a high standard deviation and error?

Furthermore, with Span and Memory I do not have a common "typeless" interface anymore as I had with array, since there is no common "base". So would there be a way to use the Span including the Array as the example above, or is there even a better and faster solution?

Comment: There are no meaningful differences between these methods, they all take the same amount of time.  Chasing down 100 microseconds on an operation repeated a million times requires explaining why the operation takes 100 *picoseconds* longer.  That's not feasible when it takes a processor ~300 picoseconds to execute an instruction.  Such very small differences can be explained away by variable clock rates, the clock slows down when the chip gets hot.  And speeds back up when the fan turns on.

Comment: @HansPassant: Agreed, but do you think that the last benchmark also suffers from this? I cannot explain why the most primitive method is the best in that case. Does the jitter really optimize that good?